Cloudfront returning 502 errors when trying from Postman
I am new to AWS , I am trying to integrate AWS CloudFront with my Api Gateway to save network calls. But I am getting error while trying to access CloudFront URL from postman. I have created my stack using AWS SAM . I have created CloudFront manually from console also using https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mNdv8uy1xrA and it is working fine. But the one I have created via below template.yml giving error "Failed to contact the origin." and 502 Gateway.
Error Logs in S3 via Standard logging
2024-04-15  14:53:15    DEL54-C3    900 49.36.144.184   GET d2glumke17n45k.cloudfront.net   /dev/product/getAllProducts 502 -   PostmanRuntime/7.37.3   -   -   Error   YjzB7kmRc9c9YGAcD_lhe6-fKvZeokBeUfk0AcW-3sYr3hvxROoLBQ==    d2glumke17n45k.cloudfront.net   https   242 0.175   -   TLSv1.3 TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256  Error   HTTP/1.1    -   -   60635   0.175   OriginDnsError  text/html   507 -   -

template.yml
ProductInfoSamFunction:
Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
Properties:
  Handler: com.amway.valuechain.handler.LambdaHandler::handleRequest
  CodeUri: .
  Runtime: java17
  AutoPublishAlias: live
  SnapStart:
    ApplyOn: PublishedVersions
  Architectures:
    - x86_64
  MemorySize: 2048  
  Events:
    ProductApiEvents:
      Type: Api
      Properties:
        Path: /{proxy+}
        Method: ANY
        RestApiId: !Ref ProductAPI  # Add this line
        
MyCloudFrontDistribution:
Type: 'AWS::CloudFront::Distribution'
Properties:
  DistributionConfig:
    Enabled: true
    Origins:
      - Id: SamApiOrigin
        DomainName: !Sub '${ProductInfoSamFunction}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com'
        CustomOriginConfig:
          HTTPPort: 80
          HTTPSPort: 443
          OriginProtocolPolicy: https-only
    DefaultCacheBehavior:
      TargetOriginId: SamApiOrigin
      ViewerProtocolPolicy: https-only
      DefaultTTL: 30 # Set DefaultTTL to 30 seconds
      AllowedMethods:
        - GET
        - HEAD
      CachedMethods:
        - GET
        - HEAD
      ForwardedValues:
          QueryString: true  
    CacheBehaviors:
      - PathPattern: /dev/*  # Path pattern to match requests starting with /dev/
        TargetOriginId: SamApiOrigin
        ViewerProtocolPolicy: https-only
        AllowedMethods:
          - GET
          - HEAD
        CachedMethods:
          - GET
          - HEAD
        ForwardedValues:
          QueryString: true
        DefaultTTL: 30    
    DefaultRootObject: index.html

